# In this sentence, what are the main subject and the main verb?

Tags: verbs, adverbs, conjunctions, subjects

Consider the following sentence:

> Though this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her.

In that sentence, what are the main subject and the main verb? Is the word 'though' a conjunction or an adverb?

Comment: A Strange sentence...

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Those are fine questions, but you should include what you think based on your own research into the issue; that will greatly help others to write useful answers. Also, please cite all quoted text (or let us know if you wrote that sentence yourself).

Comment: It's not a sentence but just a phrase. More specifically, it's a preposition phrase with the **preposition** _though_ as head and the **clause** _this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her_ as its complement. The subject of the clause is _this_ and the matrix verb is _was_. The  function of the PP in a sentence would be **adjunct of concession**.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete or correct sentence. The subject and verb depend on how exactly you fix the sentence.

Let's fix the sentence:

"Though this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her," she tried her best anyway.

"Though this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her," she spoke proudly.

"Though this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her," she spoke for a long time anyway, with only crickets and the wind as audience members.

> Question 1. In this sentence, what is the main subject and the verb?

The sentence fragment contains independent clauses if you slice it up. This doesn't mean it has a main subject and verb. These don't exist. Let's fix the sentence in other ways, and then analyze it:

"This was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her."

Subject: this.
Verb: was.

"Though this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, there was no one to listen to her."

Subject: there.
Verb: was.

> Question 2. In this sentence, is 'though' conjunction? or adverb?

"Though" is a conjunction here. It introduces a subordinate clause and shows a contrast with the main clause.

Comment: "The sentence fragment contains independent clauses". They are *dependent clauses* since both use subordinating conjunctions.

Answer (score 0):

> "Though this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her."

In that sentence the main subject is the word **"this"** and the main verb is the word **"was"**.

The word **"though"** is a conjunction. I found the following similar sentence in Merriam-Webster [1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/though):

> **though**:in spite of the fact that: while (conjunction)

As an example Merriam-Webster gives the following sentence :

> **Though** they know the war is lost, they continue to fight

In the above example the word **"though"** is a conjunction.